# How to extend a search for elements and values to attributes?

Tags: xml-parsing, xquery, xquery-sql

I have an XML document like below. I am trying to get key/value pair for all elements and attributes as well. The query I have gets all elements names and element values. However, I would like to get attribute names and attribute values too (preferably in the same query, otherwise in a different query).

**XML Document:**

```
      <bookstore>
        <book category="COOKING">
            <title lang="en">Cook Book</title>
            <author>Chef Author</author>
            <year>2015</year>
            <price>310.00</price>
        </book>
        <book category="CHILDREN">
            <title lang="en">Kid Story Book</title>
            <author>KJ Banter</author>
            <year>2010</year>
            <price>229.99</price>
        </book>
        </bookstore>
```

**SQL Query in Oracle:**

```
    WITH tab AS
    (SELECT xmltype('
                 <bookstore>
        <book category="COOKING">
            <title lang="en">Cook Book</title>
            <author>Chef Author</author>
            <year>2015</year>
            <price>310.00</price>
        </book>
        <book category="CHILDREN">
            <title lang="en">Kid Story Book</title>
            <author>KJ Banter</author>
            <year>2010</year>
            <price>229.99</price>
        </book>
        </bookstore>
    ') col
    FROM dual
    )
    SELECT nodepath,nodevalue
      FROM tab t,
       xmltable('
        for $i in $tmp/descendant::*
        where $i/text() != ""
        return <R><P>{string-join($i/ancestor-or-self::*/name(), "/")}</P><V>{$i/text()}</V></R>' 
        passing t.col AS "tmp" columns
        nodepath varchar2(1000) path '//P',
        nodevalue varchar2(1000) path '//V')
```

Answer (score 1):

Given you want them in document order, descend for each retrieved element and follow its self- and attribute axis. You need to retrieve element and attribute values differently, so apply a `typeswitch`:

```
for $node in /descendant::*/(., @*)
let $value := (
  typeswitch ($node)
  case element() return $node/text()
  case attribute() return data($node)
  default return ()
)
where $value
return <R>
  <P>{
    string-join(($node/name(), $node/ancestor::*/name()), "/")
  }</P>
  <V>{ $value }</V>
</R>
```

Also observe I changed the `ancestor-or-self` step to an `ancestor` step and explicitly return `$node`'s name, so we don't have to distinguish between elements and attributes again in the `ancestor` axis.

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick response @Jens Erat.  When I implemented your solution, I am getting an error "invalid arguments to fn:data()". I am new to xQuery. I believe I may have to use something like "return data($node/@*)" and not "$node/data()". I could not quite figure out the syntax. I really appreciate your help on this.

Comment: I'm sorry, I mixed in some XQuery 3.0 notation/syntactic sugar. Just swap `$node/data()` with `data($node)`. I updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Some background why `$node/data()` does not work, but `$node/text()` and `$node/name()` do: `[fn:]data()` is a function, while `text()` and `name()` are node tests. Functions as path steps have been added in XQuery 3.0.